# Selecting feature and highlighting based on feature properties in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I need to select link using link properties, I am able to find the feature but not able to highlight programmatically. please help..

In openlayers 2 we have selectFeature but not sure what is in ol3

Answer (score 6):

Programmatic feature selection works by manipulating the Select interaction's feature collection:

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select();
var features = select.getFeatures();
// now you have an ol.Collection of features that you can add features to
features.push(feature);
// now the pushed feature is highlighted
```

The above snippet assumes that the feature you want to highlight is assigned to the `feature` variable.

Comment: I am trying this answer and the following, but I cannot get the feature highlighted. the feature is found by another function and then added to a point layer with a specific style. This point is not added to the map until the function is over, hence the highlight is not also happening in the middle of processing. What I am missing?

Comment: could you please check my question as well: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169872/highlight-a-feature-in-ol3

Answer (score 6):

@ahocevar's answer saved me hours but one thing is missing from the code is to add select interaction to map object:

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select();
//make sure you add select interaction to map
map.addInteraction(select);
var features = select.getFeatures();
// now you have an ol.Collection of features that you can add features to
features.push(feature);
// now the pushed feature is highlighted

//to dehighlight, just simply remove the feature from select
features.remove(feature);
```

Comment: Could you also check my comment above please?!

Comment: Hi, could you also take a look at this question please? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169872/highlight-a-feature-in-ol3